# Minimap2 for Nanopore cDNA-seq alignment to reference: command not found, why?

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-seq

I am trying to map Oxford Nanopore cDNA reads to the reference using Minimap2. I am working on a macbook in the unix environment from the terminal. I have my fastq files and my reference genome downloaded, I have downloaded Minimap2 following the [tutorial on GitHub](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2) with the code:

`curl -L https://github.com/lh3/minimap2/releases/download/v2.21/minimap2-2.21_x64-linux.tar.bz2 | tar -jxvf -`

And then tried to run Minimap2 with:

`minimap2 -ax splice ref.fa nanopore-cdna.fa > aln.sam`

But the output is: `-bash: minimap2: command not found`

So it looks like minimap2 isn't installed, but I can see the folder with Unix executable file called minimap2. How do I install it?
I have very little bioinformatics experience so I apologise if this is very basic...

Thank you!

Comment: You need to either add the folder with the `minimap2` binary to your `PATH` environment variable, or give the full path when calling minimap

Comment: Thank you for your help! I specified the path when calling minimap2, and now the output is "cannot execute binary file"... I am working on an external hard drive so the path is /Volumes/HYUNDAI\ 1TB/minimap2-2.21_x64-linux/minimap2 ... Not sure if this could cause any problems?

Comment: The external drive should not be an issue. What is your Operating system. Are you on a 64 bit linux machine?

Comment: I'm on macOS Big Sur, is this the problem?

Comment: The binary you have downloaded is not compiled for MacOS. You will either need to download the source code and compile it or install from another source. Do you have ana/miniconda by any chance?

Comment: I do, I am having trouble launching Spyder at the moment but I have seen that I can use Minimap2 with Python. I'll try to sort this and attempt doing this from Spyder... Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I don't think you can use it from python, but you can do `conda install -c bioconda minimap2` and then the minimap command will be available from your normal shell

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much, you're a saviour!